# Perform Join query on mongo through nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, collections

I want to perform join statement on a mongo collection and fetch data from other collection also through a common field value

I used the following code but its not working and not returning any data when i tried through postman

```
const express = require('express')
const Product = require('../models/products')
const router = new express.Router()

router.get('/products/view', function(req, res, next) {
    Products.find(function (err, events) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(events);
    });
  });  // THIS IS WORKING BUT ONLY GIVING DATA OF ONE TABLE

router.get('/products/paginate', function(req, res, next) {
    Product.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'hsncodes',
            localField: 'hsncode',
            foreignField: 'hsncode',
            as: 'hsncodedetails'
          }
    }]);
}); // THIS IS NOT WORKING
```

Comment: I think it should be Products.aggregate() , you forgot the 's' in the end maybe , and if it still doesn't work then try removing the 's' in the from : 'hsncodes' . what I mean is to address the collection in singular form .

Comment: another good solution to this problem can be using virtuals in mongoose . please let me know I will write a solution to this problem using virtuals

Comment: Products cannot be because my model name is Product

Comment: also the field name is Hsncode only then why should i add s to that

Comment: @shashwatgupta ??